# How do you extract only urls from mysql query in Codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter

This is how my query looks like the Controller :

```
public function index(){
    $this->load->library('lib_pagination');                         
    $pg_config['sql']      = "SELECT * from SjohlLBzads_products JOIN SjohlLBzads_products_meta ON SjohlLBzads_products.post_id = SjohlLBzads_products_meta.post_id ";              
    $pg_config['per_page'] = 50;                                     
    $data = $this->lib_pagination->create_pagination($pg_config);   
    $this->load->view("product_listing", $data);                      
    }
```

This is how how I display it in the view (`product_listing.php`)

```
<?php echo $data->gallery; ?>
```

The problem is the results I got from it not sorted out and contain mix of url and text :

```
a:6:{i:0;s:159:"https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/HTB1AHOBOVXXXXazXpXXq6xXFXXXf/COLROVIE-Work-Summer-Style-Women-Bodycon-Dresses-Sexy-2017-New-Arrival-Casual-Green-Crew-Neck-Half.jpg";i:1;s:159:"https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/HTB1ov9LOVXXXXbMXXXXq6xXFXXXl/COLROVIE-Work-Summer-Style-Women-Bodycon-Dresses-Sexy-2017-New-Arrival-Casual-Green-Crew-Neck-Half.jpg";i:2;s:159:"https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/HTB1e4eHOVXXXXcbXXXXq6xXFXXXG/COLROVIE-Work-Summer-Style-Women-Bodycon-Dresses-Sexy-2017-New-Arrival-Casual-Green-Crew-Neck-Half.jpg";i:3;s:159:"https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/HTB10qQ2RVXXXXbfXpXXq6xXFXXX5/COLROVIE-Work-Summer-Style-Women-Bodycon-Dresses-Sexy-2017-New-Arrival-Casual-Green-Crew-Neck-Half.jpg";i:4;s:159:"https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/HTB164c0RVXXXXaSXpXXq6xXFXXXF/COLROVIE-Work-Summer-Style-Women-Bodycon-Dresses-Sexy-2017-New-Arrival-Casual-Green-Crew-Neck-Half.jpg";i:5;s:159:"https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/HTB1OvumOVXXXXcqXFXXq6xXFXXXs/COLROVIE-Work-Summer-Style-Women-Bodycon-Dresses-Sexy-2017-New-Arrival-Casual-Green-Crew-Neck-Half.jpg";}
```

Is there any way that I can extract those 4 urls and call/display them separately ?

Comment: can you post your url here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this will help you :
Use `unserialize` to decode  `$data->gallery` like this

```
$string = 'a:6:{i:0;s:159:"https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/HTB1AHOBOVXXXXazXpXXq6xXFXXXf/COLROVIE-Work-Summer-Style-Women-Bodycon-Dresses-Sexy-2017-New-Arrival-Casual-Green-Crew-Neck-Half.jpg";i:1;s:159:"https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/HTB1ov9LOVXXXXbMXXXXq6xXFXXXl/COLROVIE-Work-Summer-Style-Women-Bodycon-Dresses-Sexy-2017-New-Arrival-Casual-Green-Crew-Neck-Half.jpg";i:2;s:159:"https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/HTB1e4eHOVXXXXcbXXXXq6xXFXXXG/COLROVIE-Work-Summer-Style-Women-Bodycon-Dresses-Sexy-2017-New-Arrival-Casual-Green-Crew-Neck-Half.jpg";i:3;s:159:"https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/HTB10qQ2RVXXXXbfXpXXq6xXFXXX5/COLROVIE-Work-Summer-Style-Women-Bodycon-Dresses-Sexy-2017-New-Arrival-Casual-Green-Crew-Neck-Half.jpg";i:4;s:159:"https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/HTB164c0RVXXXXaSXpXXq6xXFXXXF/COLROVIE-Work-Summer-Style-Women-Bodycon-Dresses-Sexy-2017-New-Arrival-Casual-Green-Crew-Neck-Half.jpg";i:5;s:159:"https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/HTB1OvumOVXXXXcqXFXXq6xXFXXXs/COLROVIE-Work-Summer-Style-Women-Bodycon-Dresses-Sexy-2017-New-Arrival-Casual-Green-Crew-Neck-Half.jpg";}';

/*Replace $data->gallery with $string*/

$arr = unserialize($string);
print_r($arr);
```

Working example : https://eval.in/1000844

For more : http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php

Comment: How do I take from $data->gallery and unserialize them ?

Comment: just before passing to the view unserialize it

Comment: it helps a lot pradeep.

now, how do I display those urls inside <img src="arrays"/> ?

Comment: you can use foreach loop it iterate the links and echo images within loop with img tag

Comment: one last question, could you show me how to join more tables into this ?

$pg_config['sql']      = "SELECT * from SjohlLBzads_products JOIN SjohlLBzads_products_meta ON SjohlLBzads_products.post_id = SjohlLBzads_products_meta.post_id ON table C.post_id ON table D.post_id on table E.post_id";

Comment: why don't you use codeigniter querybuilder for database queries : https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html

Comment: $this->db->select("*");
        $this->db->from("SjohlLBzads_products");
        $this->db->join('SjohlLBzads_products_meta', 'SjohlLBzads_products_meta.post_id = SjohlLBzads_products.post_id');
        $query = $this->db->get();
        print_r($query->result());

Comment: I got Message: Undefined property: Product_details::$db

Comment: i join only one table to join another do it same way